# How do I write a code that identifies coworker flows between firms?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, panel-data

I am struggling to write a code that first identifies coworker flows between two firms, and secondly creates a variable for mergers if the overlap is greater than 50%. Unfortunately, I only have firm, person and year id to do so.

I have unsuccessfully tried the code below and thus would appreciate any help :)

```
firm_worker_list <- dataframe %>%
  group_by(firm, year) %>%
  summarise(workers = list(unique(person))) %>%
  ungroup()

merger_candidates <- list()

for(year in unique(firm_worker_list$year)) {
  
  year_data <- filter(firm_worker_list, year == !!year)
  
  for(i in 1:(nrow(year_data) - 1)) {
    for(j in (i+1):nrow(year_data)) {
      
      overlap = sum(year_data$workers[[i]] %in% year_data$workers[[j]])
      total = length(unique(c(year_data$workers[[i]], year_data$workers[[j]])))
      
      if(overlap / total > 0.4) {
        merger_candidates <- append(merger_candidates, 
                                    list(data.frame(year = year, 
                                                    firm_a = year_data$firm[i], 
                                                    firm_b = year_data$firm[j], 
                                                    overlap = overlap, 
                                                    total = total)))
      }
    }
  }
}

merger_candidates <- bind_rows(merger_candidates)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need some test data, together with your expected output, based on that test data.

Comment: Also, you say you want to merge "...if the overlap is greater than 50%" but have `if(overlap / total > 0.4)` in your code.  This appears to be inconsistent.